# Spring GracefulShutdown being called twice in k8s

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud

It seems that my spring application is calling the graceful shutdown twice in k8s deployment. Does anyone had similar issue ?

```json
{"level":"INFO","message":"Commencing graceful shutdown. Waiting for active requests to complete","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.GracefulShutdown","thread":"SpringApplicationShutdownHook"}
{"level":"INFO","message":"Graceful shutdown complete","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.GracefulShutdown","thread":"tomcat-shutdown"}
{"level":"INFO","message":"Commencing graceful shutdown. Waiting for active requests to complete","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.GracefulShutdown","thread":"SpringApplicationShutdownHook"}
{"level":"INFO","message":"Graceful shutdown complete","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.GracefulShutdown","thread":"tomcat-shutdown"}
{"level":"INFO","message":"Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'","traceId":"","spanId":"","requestId":"","user":"","logger":"org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean","thread":"SpringApplicationShutdownHook"}
```

My application properties:

```
spring:
  lifecycle:
    timeout-per-shutdown-phase: 20s
server:
  shutdown: graceful
```

My simplified deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-api
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-container
          image: my-api
          ports:
            - name: container-port
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: metrics
              containerPort: 8081
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: ["sh", "-c", "sleep 10"]
        - name: cloud-sql-proxy
          image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.30.0
          command:
            - "/cloud_sql_proxy"
            - "-ip_address_types=PRIVATE"
            - "-structured_logs"
            - "-verbose=false"
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: ["sh", "-c", "sleep 10"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It behaves this way because you have app and actuator on different ports (at least I guess that from you Deployment descriptor). Check your startup log and you should see something like:

```
o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer                        Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol                          Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol                          Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer                        Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer                        Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol                          Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol                          Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer                        Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
```

So when the application is closed, both of these are shut down.